# Enabling PHP's SSH2 extension with nginx

Tags: php, centos, nginx

Okay, so normally my sysadmin takes care of this, but he's been rather slack lately and I cannot wait any longer.

I've used PECL to install PHP's ssh2 extension. I've put the `extension=ssh2.so` in the php.ini and checked the ssh2.so is in the `extension_dir`. When I `php -m | grep ssh2`, it displays `ssh2`. When I run this script:

```
<?php

if (function_exists('ssh2_connect'))
{
    echo "true";
}

?>
```

and run it from the command line, it echos `true`.

When I run `phpinfo()` through the webserver, I can't find `ssh2` anywhere. When I run `ssh2_connect()` through the webserver, it tells me that the function is undefined.

My OS is CentOS 5.7
PHP Version 5.2.14
nginx/0.7.67

I've been looking all over Google and tried everything I could find, but I can't figure it out. Can anyone help?

**EDIT:**

Just to keep you guys updated, Shish was right. I found a program `php-fpm`, that when called, seems to be what I'm looking for. However, it's failing to load the ssh2 extension due to mismatched API numbers

```
Starting php_fpm PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ssh2: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
 done
```

After some short research, it seems it might be an issue of me installing the ssh2 module via PECL, and I believe my sysadmin compiled PHP from source.

Looking into it now.

**EDIT:**

After additional research, it appears two versions of PHP are installed on my system. One that I probably installed via yum, and one that my sysadmin probably installed. It appears `php-fpm` is loading the one he installed, and naturally my updates aren't affecting it. Perhaps I'll wait for him in case I screw something up.

**EDIT:**

On second thought, I'm just going to remove everything and try it myself. At worst I'll just need to get him to reinstall everything, and at best it'll work and I won't have to wait for him any longer. Wish me luck.

**EDIT:**

Nope. Scratch that. No idea what I'm doing. I think I hate my life. I have about 30 tabs open in Chrome now. I'm going to bed. Hopefully someone can provide further insight while I sleep.

**EDIT:**

Yup, probably destroyed everything. Gonna try to repair my damage and then let my sysadmin handle it again. Going to accept the current answer because, well, it was right. Past that was just problems with the module API mismatch.

Comment: Let your sysadmin handle it! You're messing with an old version of PHP that's no longer supported by PHP, you definitely should not be doing that. Have your sysadmin clean up the install so that you only have one PHP version. You should probably also have Nginx updated while you're at it.

Comment: Yeah, I've probably just completely messed it all up. Just tired of waiting on him. It's been half a month. I'ma try to fix my damage and then just hand it all back to him. -_-

Comment: Fire him and get a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to restart the PHP daemon - if the web server is nginx, then PHP is probably running as fastcgi or under PHP-FPM. Unfortunately I don't know CentOS to know the exact command to use to restart that daemon...

Comment: I'll look into it, but I've restarted the server multiple times. I'd imagine that would have done it.

Comment: Looking into it, you're definitely onto something.

Comment: Yup. My sysadmin appears to have that set up. But now another problem. Gonna do some searching and if I still can't get it working, I'll edit my question